# Sires Circuits: The problem with Resistors and Voltage

Tags: electric-circuits

My teacher says that the current throughout a series circuit, even before entering a resistor and after exiting it. My problem has to do with the voltage drop while passing the resistor. I; and correct if I am wrong, think of voltage as the energy residing per each unit charge. If indeed there is a voltage drop, so will a drop in energy per each unit charge will occur. Will this not in turn affect the velocity of the electrons (their kinetic energy), and then the current?

Comment: Please read your question again. Im having trouble figuring out what you are trying to say and ask.

Answer (score 1):

As they travel around a circuit the mobile charges lose electric potential energy (voltage drop), gain kinetic energy, collide with lattice ions losing kinetic energy, lose electric potential energy (another drop in voltage), gain kinetic energy, collide with lattice ions losing kinetic energy, and so on.

Thus the mobile charge carriers are all the time speeding up and then slowing down.
As a result of this behaviour you can assign an "average" speed for the mobile charge carriers which is called the "drift velocity".